# Expressions as a product of disjoint cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra

Express (i) $(136275)(6453)(245)$ and (ii) $(1245)(253)$ as a product of disjoint cycles.

I have researched as much as I can online including other posts but I just can't seem to fathom this concept.I would appreciate any approaches for answering these questions, currently I have been attempting them with whats been called the "chase the number" approach

Answer (score 0):

Try to prove theses properties: ($i_1,i_2,\cdots,i_{n+m}$ are distinct)

(i) $(i_1 i_2\cdots i_n)(i_n i_{n+1}\cdots i_{n+m})=(i_1\cdots i_{n+m})$

(ii) $(i_1i_2\cdots i_n)=(i_1i_n)(i_1i_{n-1})\cdots(i_1i_2)$

(iii) $(i_1i_2)(i_1i_3)\cdots(i_1i_n)(i_1i_2)=(i_2i_3)\cdots(i_2i_n)$

This will help you solve all this kind of questions.

For example:
$(1245)(253)=(2451)(253)=(21)(25)(24)(23)(25)=(21)(54)(53)=(12)(345).$